# How to flash Stock Recovery without PC

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, rooting

I'm trying to get back to stock recovery. Currently I don't have access to a PC. A few days ago, when I tried flashing the recovery.tar file via Odin, it failed. How can I get back to stock recovery? I have the recovery file in both formats i.e. .img and .tar. 
Any help will be appreciated.

My Device : Galaxy Tab 4 SM-T531 Android 4.4.3 Stock

[image: The Recovery Files]

Comment: By "don't have a PC" do you literally mean you don't have access to a desktop or laptop computer, or do you mean you're using a Mac?

Comment: Provided that your device is rooted, you can use various apps to flash recovery without PC. Notable ones are [Flashify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.flashify&hl=en) and [Rashr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mkrtchyan.recoverytools)

Comment: @NDGeek I don't have access to a PC at the moment.

Comment: @Firelord I tried flashify but It didn't worked. After flashing with flashify when I reboot it boots into download mode saying couldn't do normal boot.

Comment: You can also use mobile Odin for this purpose. Look on play store ;)

Answer (score -1):

Oooo also download pem it generates passwors for when you extract the tar file in mobile odin other way is twerp flashing it

Comment: See our community guidelines on [How to answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)